# How do I open a jQuery UI Accordion tab depending on a value in the heading?

Tags: jquery-ui, asp-classic, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using ASP Classic and on the page I have a jQuery UI Accordion. I want one tab of the accordion to be open depending on the value of a variable. If the value is equal to 0, I want all the tabs to be closed; if it is greater than 0, I want that Accordion section to be open. This is what I currently have:

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
});
```

HTML/ASP:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Tab1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Tab2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Tab3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Results (<%=number%>)</h3> <!--This is the tab-->
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want said script to run on page load? Also, are you able to modify the markup such that the <h3> element with your "Results" and number variable has an ID and/or a custom HTML attribute such as "data-ResultCount"? If so, that will make checking for your value much easier & better performing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you for the help everyone.

I know hundreds of you tried to help but after two attempts of asking the question, I have done it myself. I wish I wasn't a genius, but what is your loss is my gain. If you are remotely interested in how I solved this question then please look below.

jQuery

```
$Results = '<%=Session("Results")%>';

    if ($Results > 0) {
        $(function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                heightStyle: "content",
                collapsible: true,
                active: 4
            });
        });
     } else {
        $(function() {
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                heightStyle: "content",
                collapsible: true,
                active: false
            });
        });
    }
```

HTML/ASP

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Tab1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Tab2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Tab3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Results (<%=Session("intResults")%>)</h3> <!--This is the tab-->
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW it is jQuery and you are genius.

Comment: BTW, looks identical to me and yeah I know @Runcorn

Comment: @Runcorn Thanks for the down vote :), I suppose I didn't need to say I was a genius when its so evident tham I am.